# How to parse Python datetime.str output with strptime?

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I am getting timestamps from a REST server which creates them using `datetime.str()`. This gives me a timestamp that looks like: `'2018-02-21 10:40:35+00:00'`. However, `datetime.strptime` only supports `%z` which requires the trailing timezone offset to be in the form `+/-nnnn` with no colon. The exact error looks like:

```
In[16]: str(dt)
Out[16]: '2018-02-21 10:40:35+00:00'
In[17]: datetime.strptime(str(dt), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")
ValueError: time data '2018-02-21 10:40:35+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z'
```

Is there a `strptime` flag that will parse the trailing `"+00:00"` as-is, or do I need to resort to `str.rpartition` tricks before calling `strptime`?

Comment: `strptime` documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) mentions only one valid standard for the TZ offset: without the colon.

Comment: It is annoying that the default `str()` for datetime emits the timezone with the colon, which has no `strptime`-parseable analog.